# What's the best way to get the duration of an API call using Guzzle 6

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

Currently with Guzzle 6 it seems there's no out of the box way to get the duration of an API call. What's the best way to get this stat with any ordinary call using the code below.

I'm using the following code from [How do you log all API calls using Guzzle 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681165/how-do-you-log-all-api-calls-using-guzzle-6)

```
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
use GuzzleHttp\Middleware;
use GuzzleHttp\MessageFormatter;
use Monolog\Logger;

$stack = HandlerStack::create();
$stack->push(
    Middleware::log(
        new Logger('Logger'),
        new MessageFormatter('{req_body} - {res_body}')
    )
);
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(
    [
        'base_uri' => 'http://httpbin.org',
        'handler' => $stack,
    ]
);

echo (string) $client->get('ip')->getBody();
```

Answer (score 4):

I refer you to the 'on_stats' request option [Guzzle Docs - Request Options](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/request-options.html#on-stats)
and the [TransferStats object](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/TransferStats.php)

To implement this you would modify your get request to use request options.  It would be something like the following:

```
// get($uri, $options) proxies to request($method, $uri, $options)
// request($method, $uri, $options) proxies to requestAsync($method, $uri, $options)
// and sets the $options[RequestOptions::SYNCHRONOUS] to true
// and then waits for promises to resolve returning a Psr7\http-message\ResponseInterface instance

$response = $client->get($uri, [
    'on_stats'  => function (TransferStats $stats) use ($logger) {
        // do something inside the callable.
        echo $stats->getTransferTime() . "\n";
        $logger->debug('Request' . $stats->getRequest() . 
                       'Response' . $stat->getResponse() .
                       'Tx Time' . $stat->getTransferTime()
        );
    },
]);
echo $response->getBody();
```

**Note: I'm certain there are ways of ensuring the log is formatted nicer, however, this was to serve as a proof of concept.

The `TransferStats` are generated and used within the individual handlers, and at this time are not made available by the handler to the stack. As a result they are not available for consumption within the invidual middlewares placed upon the stack.

Comment: Any idea how to use by above code to implement the transfer stats?

Comment: I still don't get how I can send the transfertime to the handler so it can be in the same output? For example : `new MessageFormatter('{req_body} - {res_body} - {REQUEST_TIME}')`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment but just to improve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32743755/2761550) answer

```
$response = $client->post($uri, [
    RequestOptions::JSON => $postData,
    RequestOptions::ON_STATS => function (TransferStats $stats) use ($logger) {
        $formatter = new MessageFormatter('{"request":{"uri":"{uri}","body":{req_body}},"response":{"code":{code},"body":{res_body}},"time":'.$stats->getTransferTime().'}');
        $message = $formatter->format($stats->getRequest(), $stats->getResponse());

        $logger->info($message);
    },
]);
```

P.S.: This code is for Guzzle 7