# plivo api intallation via composer conflict with guzzle

Tags: composer-php, plivo, guzzle6

I am installating plivo api using composer on live server(digital ocean), which running command i getting some dependencies version mismatch errors.
plivo required guzzle latest version, but guzzle is already installed in my laravel application but its version is old.What i need to do to resolve this error.
please help me to resolve those.
here is the composer.json

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
    "laracasts/flash": "^1.3",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "~2.0",
    "orchestra/imagine": "~3.0",
    "zendframework/zendsearch": "dev-master",
    "mmanos/laravel-search": "dev-master",
    "dimsav/laravel-translatable": "~5.0",
    "twilio/sdk": "*",
    "fillup/nexmo": "dev-master",
    "guzzlehttp/log-subscriber": "^1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
    "illuminate/html": "~5.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
                    "Lib\\": "lib/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}}
```

here is the screen shot
[image]

Comment: Please show your `composer.json` file.

Comment: @xabbuh  which one , the file on root ?

Comment: yes, the one from your project

Comment: @xabbuh i have now added my comoser.json file contents , please check

Comment: You have to decide which packages to use then (both `fillup/nexmo` and `guzzlehttp/log-subscriber` require more recent Guzzle versions).

Comment: Sidenote - making the decision easier: `guzzlehttp/log-subscriber` is deprecated/abandoned, see https://github.com/guzzle/log-subscriber

Answer (score 1):

Plivo Sales Engineer here.

You should not use `guzzlehttp/log-subscriber` (it is depreciated as noted in the comments) but rather use any logger which implements a PSR-3 interface. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681165/how-do-you-log-all-api-calls-using-guzzle-6) for how to do it with the builtin guzzle middleware and `monolog` or there is also the [guzzle-log-middleware](https://github.com/rtheunissen/guzzle-log-middleware).

One other note: the latest version of `plivo-php` is 1.1.0. I'd encourage you to use that. It requires Guzzle v6.1.1.

Comment: while installing guzzle-log-middleware , i am getting error that it requires latest verion of guzzle. how can i configure this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [plivo/plivo-php](https://packagist.org/packages/plivo/plivo-php), it requires Guzzle v6.1.
[guzzlehttp\log-subscriber](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/log-subscriber) is only compatible with Guzzle v4 and v5.

If you are attempting to log the Request or Response you can use [GuzzleHttp\Middleware::log](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Middleware.php#L182)

Comment: where i need to add this, i haven't understand you answer.