# Log, debug, analyze HTTP requests within server-side framework views

Tags: php, http, debugging, server-side, har

We are exploring the use of a PHP framework, [Slim](https://www.slimframework.com/), and are interested in the ability to log, debug, and analyze all sever-side HTTP requests that framework views are making.  We would like to see the results of those requests client-side.

For example.  We have a route `/foo`.  The view for route `/foo` makes three API calls to an API on the server, interprets those results, and returns a response.  We would like to see the request parameters, header information, and response from those three server-side HTTP requests from the comfort of our browser.  We've seen client-side debugging tools like the [PHP Debug Bar](http://phpdebugbar.com/), which looks like good scaffolding for displaying information from the server-side HTTP requests, but aren't clear how it would record and/or know of those server-side requests.

Previously, all of our API calls were made from the client and it was trivial to observe and debug these in browser development tools.

We've stumbled across standards such as [HTTP Archive logs (HARs)](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec/) that were made for capturing HTTP requests/response transactions in JSON form; is there way to record and bubble this up?  More specifically, are there debugging tools in place for PHP frameworks that might have all this wrapped up in a tidy bow?

This would be for debugging only, as obviously it would make each route render much heavier for returning all that information around those server-side HTTP requests.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be most welcome!

Comment: With regard to the API calls, I think that will depend on which library you are going to use to make those server side HTTP calls. If you use Guzzle with Monolog as logging library, you could implement something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/32684940/1882337. But if you are going to use simple curl_exec() methods, you are probably going to need to build the logging yourself.

Comment: Thanks @wessel-van-der-linden, that's helpful.  I'm not terribly familiar with modern PHP frameworks, was floating this for our team which is exploring debugging approaches for a new implementation.  The 'guzzle-log-middleware' mentioned in that post might turn out to be quite helpful.