# Is possible to log all Guzzle requests globally?

Tags: php, guzzle

I am working on a PHP project that uses [thephpleague/oauth2-client](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client).  I am using `oauth2-client` to start a session and then use the credentials in `guzzle` to request additional resources from RESTful services.  For troubleshooting, I would like to log all requests, including the ones by `oauth2-client`.

`oauth2-client` also uses `guzzle` to make its requests.  I see that we can use [`debug => true`](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#debug-option) when creating a client in my code, but is there a way to configure this globally for `guzzle` so I can also see the calls from `oauth2-client` as well?

Comment: Can't you set `debug => true` when creating the `oauth2-client` request object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, you can. Just pass your global instance of Guzzle's HTTP client to your OAuth provider. See [this code for details](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client/blob/master/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php#L127).

For logging itself [there is a question already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681165/how-do-you-log-all-api-calls-using-guzzle-6).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!