# How to dynamic replace guzzle in laravel

Tags: laravel

I see in `https://github.com/hannesvdvreken/guzzle-clockwork/blob/4.x/src/Support/Laravel/ServiceProvider.php`

use `$this->app->bind(ClinetInterface::class ...` to create an guzzlehttp\client instance.
but not working to me.

```
// provider/custom func register
$this->app->bind(Client::class, function () { throw new Exception(); })
// app.php
'prodiders' => [ app\provider\custom.php]
// app/console/commands/test.php
new GuzzleHttp\Client()
```

it's not work.

multi guzzlehttp use cases in my proj.
i want dynamic replace the `Client` instance and inject a middleware direct return the fake response (mock data), how can i do this?

versions:
laravel : 6.9.0
guzzlehttp/guzzle : 6.5.2

Comment: As I can see in GuzzleHttp library there is Middleware. There you can find functions, and maybe you can find what you need. So in your code add: 'use GuzzleHttp\Middleware;'

Comment: What is to say try something like that:
$dynamicClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Middleware();

$response2 = $dynamicClient::mapResponse();
...

Comment: @Tinxuanna The proj have multi developer and every people just direct use `new \GuzzleHttp\Client` to request thirdparty http api, now I want to record the logs of all guzzles used globally without modifying the code of others.

Comment: Maybe you can check the answers given in the link: [log api calls using guzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681165/how-do-you-log-all-api-calls-using-guzzle-6). Give it a try, and when you are stuck again, feel free to ask.